# SQL Trigger Inconsistently firing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have a SQL Trigger on a table that works... most of the time. And I cannot figure out why sometimes the fields are NULL

The trigger works by Updateing the LastUpdateTime whenever something is modified in the field, and the InsertDatetime when first Created.

For some reason this only seems to work some times.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DateTriggerTheatreListHeaders]
   ON  [dbo].[TheatreListHeaders]
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
BEGIN
        UPDATE ES
                SET InsertDatetime = Getdate()
                ,LastUpdateDateTime = Getdate()
                FROM TheatreListHeaders es
                JOIN Inserted I ON es.UNIQUETHEATRELISTNUMBER = I.UNIQUETHEATRELISTNUMBER

END 
IF UPDATE(LastUpdateDateTime) OR UPDATE(InsertDatetime)
    RETURN;

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        INSERTED I
        JOIN
        DELETED D
            -- make sure to compare inserted with (same) deleted person
            ON D.UNIQUETHEATRELISTNUMBER = I.UNIQUETHEATRELISTNUMBER

    )
BEGIN
        UPDATE ES
                SET InsertDatetime = ISNULL(es.Insertdatetime,Getdate())
                ,LastUpdateDateTime = Getdate()
                FROM TheatreListHeaders es
                JOIN Inserted I ON es.UNIQUETHEATRELISTNUMBER = I.UNIQUETHEATRELISTNUMBER

END
END
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? That code is product specific.

Comment: The trigger was made using SSMS and is on the triggers section of the table. The original Database was created using Clarion.

Comment: The <sql-server> tag is just fine!

Comment: When you say "The fields are *`NULL`*", which feilds are we specifically talking about here? `InsertDatetime `, `LastUpdateDateTime` or both? Do you notice the issue seems to happen more during an `INSERT` or `UPDATE`? Sometimes it's actually easier to separate `UPDATE` and `INSERT` triggers, rather having one doing different logic for the 2.

Comment: InsertDateTime and LastUpdateTime are both null when it doesn't work, there is no instance of one or the other being null, it's both or neither.

I'm not sure if it's updates or inserts that are causing the issue, since this is happening on a front end system and I'm just seeing the end results on the back end

Comment: i think you may need a left join for inserted and deleted as there might not be deleted records for the same key and therefore it won't update after insert

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler and efficient approach to do what you are trying to do, would be something like...

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DateTriggerTheatreListHeaders]
   ON  [dbo].[TheatreListHeaders]
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

--Determine if this is an INSERT OR UPDATE Action .
DECLARE @Action as char(1);
    SET @Action = (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                         AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
                        THEN 'U'  -- Set Action to Updated.
                        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                        THEN 'I'  -- Set Action to Insert.   
                    END);

UPDATE ES
    SET  InsertDatetime     = CASE WHEN @Action = 'U' 
                                    THEN ISNULL(es.Insertdatetime,Getdate()) 
                                    ELSE  Getdate()
                              END
        ,LastUpdateDateTime = Getdate()
FROM TheatreListHeaders es
JOIN Inserted I ON es.UNIQUETHEATRELISTNUMBER = I.UNIQUETHEATRELISTNUMBER;

END
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is happening on a Live production system, and they are asking for answers, so while I will definitely look into simplifying the code at a later date, i'm currently trying to figure out of there is anything outright "wrong" with it

Comment: Well if the issue is in Production, surely, fixing the issue should be the first priority and then at later stage collate all the information you can to log the incident/issue :)

Answer (score 0):

"If update()" is poorly defined/implemented in sql server IMO. It does not do what is implied. The function only determines if the column was set by a value in the triggering statement. For an insert, every column is implicitly (if not explicitly) assigned a value. Therefore it is not useful in an insert trigger and difficult to use in a single trigger that supports both inserts and updates. Sometimes it is better to write separate triggers.

Are you aware of recursive triggers? An insert statement will execute your trigger which updates the same table. This causes the trigger to execute again, etc. Is the (database) recursive trigger option off (which is typical) or adjust your logic to support that?

What are your expectations for the insert/update/merge statements against this table? This goes back to your requirements. Is the trigger to ignore any attempt to set the datetime columns directly and set them within the trigger **always**?

And lastly, what exactly does "works sometimes" actually mean? Do you have a test case that reproduces your issue. If you don't, then you can't really "fix" the logic without a specific failure case. But the above comments should give you sufficient clues. To be honest, your logic seems to be overly complicated. I'll add that it also is logically flawed in the way that it set insertdatetime to getdate if the existing value is null during an update. IMO, it should reject any update that attempts to set the value to null because that is overwriting a fact that **should never change**.  M.Ali has provided an example that is usable but includes the created timestamp problem. Below is an example that demonstrates a different path (assuming the recursive trigger option is off). It does not include the rejection logic - which you should consider. Notice the output of the merge execution carefully.

```
use tempdb;
set nocount on;
go

create table zork (id integer identity(1, 1) not null primary key, 
    descr varchar(20) not null default('zippy'), 
    created datetime null, modified datetime null); 
go
create trigger zorktgr on zork for insert, update as 
begin
    declare @rc int = @@rowcount;
    if @rc = 0 return;
    set nocount on;

   if update(created) 
        select 'created column updated', @rc as rc;
   else
        select 'created column NOT updated', @rc as rc;

    if exists (select * from deleted) -- update :: do not rely on @@rowcount
       update zork set modified = getdate()
       where exists (select * from inserted as ins where ins.id = zork.id);
    else
       update zork set created = getdate(), modified = getdate()
       where exists (select * from inserted as ins where ins.id = zork.id);
end;
go

insert zork default values; 
select * from zork;

insert zork (descr) values ('bonk');
select * from zork;

update zork set created = null, descr = 'upd #1' where id = 1;
select * from zork;

update zork set descr = 'upd #2' where id = 1;
select * from zork;
waitfor delay '00:00:02';

merge zork as tgt 
using (select 1 as id, 'zippity' as descr union all select 5, 'who me?') as src 
on tgt.id = src.id 
when matched then update set descr = src.descr
when not matched then insert (descr) values (src.descr)
;
select * from zork;
go
drop table zork;
```